# Cancel API call when modal closes - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have a condition where I keep fetching API's every 2.5 seconds until the data at the path mentioned is resolved. I am using this inside a modal. The call is made every 2.5 seconds until the data is resolved. However, if the data isnt resolved and I plan to close the modal, the API call is still being made. How do I clear the timeout and stop the API call on close button click of modal? Please advice. Also, if the API isnt resolved in the 5th try, I would like to reject it .

```js
const getData = (url, path) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const loop = (async () => {
                const result = await axios.get(url);
                if (_.has(result.data, path) && result.data[path]) {
                    resolve(result.data[path]); // Resolve with the data
                    return; // Stop the loop
                }
                setTimeout(loop, 2500);
            })();
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e)
        }
    });
}

(async() => {
  const version = await getData('https://api.oceandrivers.com/static/resources.json', 'swaggerVersion');
  console.log(version);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Where should I place the clearInterval? Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You should clear the timeout when the modal unmounts. You can do this by using the useEffect hook in the modal component and then do this:

```
const timeout = setTimeout(loop, 2500)
useEffect(()=>{return clear timeout(timeout)},[]);
```

Apologies for the code formatting, I'm on mobile.

Comment: I do not have access to the method loop as its inside getData method.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: I understand this. But I do want to clearTimeout the loop method inside getData

Comment: Then pass a callback in to getData that gets called and clears the timeout when the modal unmounts